# What is the reason for V-neck Titzis?

Tags: halacha, minhag, clothing, tallit-katan

When buying Tzitzis, I have seen that there are two types of garment:

1. A "round" neck (the hole has a racetrack shape).
2. A "V" neck (the hole for the neck has a diamond shape).

What is the reason for the V-Neck (or what is the reason for the "round Neck")?

[image]

Courtesy of [Ben's Tallit Shop](http://www.tallit-shop.com/tallit-katan/)

Comment: The same reason there are v-neck undershirts, no doubt.

Comment: As @HodofHod said, I'm sure the reason is nothing more than comfort. That being said, one thing to watch out for is that the Ba'al HaTanya wrote in his Siddur (he may have brought it in the Shulchan Aruch as well, I don't remember) that the Tallit Katan has to be 1 cubit from the neck to the end. using a v-neck will eat into that space, so make sure it is still a cubit: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/6.htm

Comment: The V neck in your picture is almost certainly style oriented. However the woolen V necks with flaps seem to be used exclusively in some hassidic circles. The same is true of the round neck wool ones which are practically exclusively used by yeshivish people. Someone told me some reason long ago what exactly the point was but I don't remember what it was.

Answer (score 3):

The important characteristics of the garment are about the corners, size, material, and how open the sides are (see below).  The choice of neckline would be governed by what you're going to wear it under, same as for any other undershirt.

[Laws of Tzitzit from Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927994/jewish/Laws-of-Tzitzit.htm) gives the following requirements for the tallit katan.  Some of the stringencies here are not universal (see comments); note, however, that these stringent requirements say nothing about the shape of the neck-hole, the subject of this question:

> It must be a garment for the body and not just the head (such as a shawl). But unlike an ordinary shirt, the four corners must include two in the front and two in the back.
>
> If the front and the back of the garment are connected at the sides, a clear majority must still be disconnected. According to the Alter Rebbe the tallit katan should be completely open on both sides and not be attached with any stitches or clasps. Certainly the garment should not have sleeves. The garment must be of a woven material, and preferably, it should be made of wool and be white.

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of firmly stated "rules" listed that directly contradict several Minhagim that some have. I wish they were more clearly indicated as being rulings of the various Lubavitch Rebbeim or customs of Chabad.

Comment: @SethJ, there are footnotes at their cite.  They give "Alter Rebbe's Shulchan Aruch 10:20" for some of this.  (Which ones are contradicted by minhagim?  I have no personal experience with this and used Chabad because many others here do so it seems to carry some weight.  If that's a bad idea in this case I'd like to know that.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have written, "There are a lot of firmly stated "rules" listed. Some of the rules contradict some people's Minhagim. I wish they more clearly indicated which statements are codified Halachah, which are rulings of the various Lubavitch Rabbeim, and which are customs of Chabad."

Comment: The Alter Rebbe in his Shulchan Aruch is very clear when something is halacha or a minhag on doesnt just state the opinion we hold of but other opinions to give a broader understanding of Halacha. With that said there is nothing wrong with wearing Kosher Tzitis that differ but the Alter Rebbe was very strict on tzitzis because of their spiritual power and protection. This is why Chabad Chassidim usually wear a gartel under their shirt to make sure their tzitzis are covering even their sides not just front and back and that the tzitzis dont fold over and leave your body exposed.

Comment: To answer your question, though, eg.: There are many Sepharadim who only wear their Tallith around their heads and over their shoulders. There are also some who put Tzitzith on shirts or jackets with sleeves if the sides of the garment are long enough and have 4 corners; in fact, it is quite common for Kapotas and Bekishes to have their corners rounded to avoid requiring Tzitzith.

Comment: @mochinrechavim, that's fine. But the website isn't following that pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the info both of you.  For the purposes of the current question, which is about the neckline (which is not mentioned at all by the Alter Rebbe here), should I delete the quoted part?  I was trying to make my answer better, not worse/distracting.

Comment: The Alter Rebbe is of the opinion that the beged of the tzitzis must be of a certain size depending on the person. Detracting from the size would make the tzitzis not follow the Alter Rebbe's opinion which is to machmir just like different opinions on a Revis or Kazayis. A v-neck detracts from the side of it since the V pieces fold over.

Comment: @SethJ Are you implying that Sephardim do not hold of wearing a Tallis Katan? I have never heard this before.

Comment: I guess I was not clear. I was referring to the Gadol only. also my second statement was not referring to any specific group or sect. It was only a general statement.

Comment: @mochinrechavim when Sepharadim make a blessing on talit kattan, the custom is to do atifa.

Comment: @SethJ We are talking about the hole in the tallis kattan. A tallis gadol is not relevant to this discussion.

Comment: Why should a talis katan "certainly" not have sleeves?  The source does not provide a source!

Comment: @MonicaCellio I do not think you should delete this post. Chabad is a reputable resource, and they accurately reflect the customs of a specific group of Jews. That is perfectly valid for an answer. However I share some of SethJ's concerns about the description not accurately reflecting the halachik minima for a tallit kattan in other groups. I expect a more canonical answer to show up soon enough. But that doesn't detract from this, so no need to delete.

Comment: @mochin how does a V neck fold the tallis over?

Comment: @DoubleAA, all: I've edited in response to these comments to note that not all hold with the stringencies in this source.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin There are 2 ways for the V. The V on cotton is cut and removed therefore decreasing the surface area of the beged which the Alter Rebbe is concerned with. The wool beged is usually cut from the hole down about 9 or so inches and the flaps foldered over. Either method is a concern of the A.R.

Comment: @SethJ: I disagree with your assessment of the article. Everything is clearly sourced in the footnotes, and in the article itself it indicates when it is not universal, e.g. "According to the Alter Rebbe". The article itself says that it is only addressing a Tallit Katan. It explicitly says not a Tallit Gadol, but the article is also not talking about regular clothes that incidentally need Tzitzit, but rather a Tallit Katan. The article definitely has a chabad slant to it, but it was written by a chabadnik.

Comment: @SethJ: With regards to the sefardic custom of wearing the tallit only on the head and shoulders, the article does not disagree with that. When he says shawl he means a head-only shawl, which, as the Mechaber says in not what the Torah obligates with Tzitzit. The Halacha itself uses the word "Mitznefet" - http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/4/10/20.htm

Comment: @mochin, I was criticizing the article, not the answer.

Comment: @Menachem, I did not feel the article was clear at all about what was Halachah vs Minhag, or that it was specifically talking about one case or one reading of the Mehaber and not making a blanket statement. None of that is obvious in a plain reading of the article, IMHO.

Comment: @Menachem, I stand corrected. The article is only about the Katan (I missed that somehow). However, as vram mentioned, some Sephardim do 'Atifah on the Katan as well and, as I mentioned, some people put Tzitzith on shirts and jackets (and others round corners of their shirts/jackets to avoid necessitating Tzitzith).

Comment: @YDK see Ketzos Hashulchan 6:3

Comment: and @SethJ ping